# Sum totals in new columns per period range SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate

I am trying to summarize total per multiple period range and display them in new columns. 
I have done simple sum function in sql but only based on one date range. 
Now I would like to show sums of totals per various date ranges.

To be honest, I don't even know how to solve this issue. I know how to show sum of totals only per one period in one column.  Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PriceTest 
> (
>      Product VARCHAR(250), 
>      Price NUMERIC(10,2), 
>      Pricedate DATETIME
> )
> ```

```
INSERT INTO PriceTest (product, price, pricedate)   VALUES ('A',
10.00,'2019/12/31'), 
       ('B', 50.00,'2019/12/31'),  
       ('C', 30.00,'2019/12/31'),  
       ('D', 50.00,'2019/12/31'),
       ('A', 20.00,'2019/10/31'), 
       ('B', 40.00,'2019/10/31'),  
       ('C', 50.00,'2019/10/31'),  
       ('D', 10.00,'2019/11/30');
```

SELECT  product, SUM (price) AS '2019-12-31'   FROM
pricetest   WHERE pricedate='2019-12-31'   GROUP BY   product,
pricedate

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:

```
product     12/31/2019
A             10
B             50
C             30
D             50
```

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query"

Comment: Thank you so much! I just found the solution by following the link you directed me too!